# Ionic action sheet : how to modify order of the buttons?

Tags: javascript, android, ionic-framework

I would like to ask, how can i modify button order in **$ionicActionSheet**? :

I need move destructiveText button on last position.

http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/service/$ionicActionSheet/

[image]

In documentation is no mention about it.

Many thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 0):

*I know you've asked a year ago but for the sake of stack I will reply.*

Simple. Just move Cancel button to buttons and add an action to hide it.

```
$ionicActionSheet.show({
        buttons: [
          { text: 'Share' },
          { text: 'Move' }, 
          { text: 'Cancel' }
        ],
        destructiveText: 'Delete',
        buttonClicked: function(index) {
          return true;
        },
        destructiveButtonClicked: function() {
           return true;
        }
      });
}
```